# Ajax POST и XMLHttpRequest и отправка значения в DataLayer для Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, google-analytics

Почти решил изначальную задачу, и теперь вот застрял на самом финале). История такая:

1. Есть AJAX калькулятор на сайте, который естественно не отсылал ничего в data.layer Google Tag Manager'а
2. А мне, конечно же, необходимо отсылать туда значения полей, выпадающих списков и прочее выбранное пользователем, чтобы это все оказалось в конечном счете в моем Google Analytics
3. Итак я установил Google Tag Manager.
4. Создал custom html tag срабатывающий после того как DOM is ready чтобы отсылать данные в data.layer следующего содержания:

   ```
   <script>
   (function() {
   var xhrOpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
   var xhrSend = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
   window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
       this.method = arguments[0];
       this.url = arguments[1];
       return xhrOpen.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
   };
   window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
       var xhr = this;
       var xhrData = arguments[0];
       var intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
           if(xhr.readyState != 4) {
               return;
           }
           dataLayer.push({
               'event': 'ajaxSuccess',
               'eventCategory': 'AJAX ' + xhr.method,
               'eventAction': xhr.url + (xhr.method == 'POST' && xhrData ? ';' + xhrData : ''),
               'eventLabel': xhr.responseText
           });
           clearInterval(intervalId);
       }, 1);
       return xhrSend.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
   };
   })();
   </script>
   ```
5. Я безумно обрадовался, что все же удалось получить хоть какую-то информацию, но к сожалению застрял на этом:

   ```
   {
       event: 'ajaxSuccess',

       eventCategory: 'AJAX POST',

       eventAction:'http://mylocalhosting.local/calculator/ajax_statistic_track;property_value=20000&state=1&property_type=1&first_home_buyer=2&are_you_purchasing=2&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnew.sharewood.ru%2Fembed.html',

       eventLabel:'property_value=20000&state=1&property_type=1&first_home_buyer=2&are_you_purchasing=2&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnew.sharewood.ru%2Fembed.html'

   }
   ```
6. Как видно из кода выше xhrData выдал мне массив параметров: параметр=значение одной строкой разделенный &. А мне же в идеале получить отдельно все эти параметры и значения
   Как мне разделить полученные в параметры и их значения? Поиск мне подсказывает что копать надо в сторону JSON.parse или JSON.stringify?
   Вот что я хотел бы получить на выходе:

   ```
   {

       event: 'ajaxSuccess',

       eventCategory: 'AJAX POST',

       eventAction:'http://mylocalhosting.local/calculator/ajax_statistic_track;property_value=20000&state=1&property_type=1&first_home_buyer=2&are_you_purchasing=2&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnew.sharewood.ru%2Fembed.html',

       eventLabel:'property_value=20000&state=1&property_type=1&first_home_buyer=2&are_you_purchasing=2&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnew.sharewood.ru%2Fembed.html'

       propertyValue: '20000',

       state: '1',

       propertyType: '1',

       firstHomeBuyer:  '2',   
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

В Google Tag Manager можно создать переменую типа dataLayer. Имя переменной будет имя параметра, в данном случае это: event, eventCategory и т.д.
Потом эти переменные можно использовать для отправки в Google Analytics, например вставив в поле category/action и т.д. при отправке события.